# When did the Altair move ROM to the top of memory?

Tags: history, 8080, cp-m, altair-8800

The 8080 starts running code at location 0 on reset. The natural layout of memory on a computer using that CPU is therefore ROM at the bottom of the memory map and RAM at the top.

CP/M demands the reverse; it insists that ROM shall be at the top. The rationale is that this allows RAM to be used 'up until when it bumps into the ROM, wherever that happens to be' i.e. the entire address space can be filled with usable RAM right up until it bumps into the ROM that is actually installed in the machine, instead of having to set aside the first X kilobytes for ROM even if not all was actually used. This requires a small amount of extra circuitry to redirect the CPU from bottom to top of the address space on reset.

CP/M originated on the Altair 8800, an 8080-based machine.

But the Altair was a streamlined, indeed downright bare-bones machine, designed to minimize cost to be affordable to hobbyists in 1975. I would not have expected it to start off with the extra circuitry to redirect the CPU on reset.

When and how did the Altair acquire that extra circuitry necessary to accommodate CP/M?

Comment: I don't think that CP/M demands it.  Boot rom can be active in memory at restart time, and then swapped out for ram when the boot loader is finished.  The CP/M machine I used did that, and had a full 64 KB RAM memory

Comment: Actually requiring RAM from zero address was a wise decision, at least for an OS (that is able to run arbitrary programs) for i8080 (that completely lacked PC-relative addressing). Other options would include the requirement for every program to be relocatable (=waste of resources) or some 'standard' ROM size at address 0 (which would exhaust soon and then again another ROM at higher addresses).

Comment: @lvd: How much would it have cost to make a 8080 program relocatable on 256-byte boundaries?  I would think that for most programs, all one would need would be to include at the start or end of the program (depending upon whether it loads at the top or bottom of RAM) a list of the offsets of all of the bytes whose value would be affected by the start address, and a loop (given as Z80 mnemonics) `ld e,(hl) / inc hl / ld a,(hl) / add a,c / ld d,a / inc hl / ld a,(de) / add a,c / ld (de),a / jp nc,lp` [the first address patched should be the jp instruction, and the last should be a dummy FF byte]

Comment: "CP/M originated on the Altair 8800, an 8080-based machine." Are you absolutely sure about that? CP/M originated on whatever Kildall used for early development, and since he was contracting for Intel it was likely to be one of their ISIS development systems or similar.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Good point! You're right, I'm sure CP/M ran on the S-100 machines, but it was probably originally developed on an Intel development system.

Comment: @supercat so in other words, a quite big list of offsets.

Comment: @user253751: The list of offsets could be jettisoned once they've been applied.  If one is using e.g. a word processor, the space which had been used to hold the offsets could be used to hold the user's document once the program is loaded.  If one is using e.g. a text adventure game that fits in memory all at once, one could load the code first, apply the offsets, and then load the text (which wouldn't need to contain any offsets) afterwards, so as to reuse the space that had held the offsets.  If loading a program from tape, the total size of the tape may exceed...

Comment: ...the memory capacity of the machine, but if one can write two load sections and either stop the tape or include the necessary amount of padding between them, the fact that the combined size exceeds the machine's memory capacity wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @user253751: Even if code would fill 95% of memory, and 10% of code bytes needed offset adjustments, one could load code that would take 80% of memory, along with the offsets that were applicable to it (which would take up the other 20%), apply those offsets, and then load code that would take 15% of memory along with the offsets for that (which would use up 3% of memory) and apply those offsets.

Comment: @user253751: Alternatively, at the expense off making the relocating code a little bit larger, one could reduce the storage used by the offsets to one byte each, plus up to one byte for every 255 bytes of the program, by storing the distance between offsets, and could eliminate the cost for most jumps whose target is within +/- 128 bytes [have the MSB of the jump target indicate far back pack the previous jump that needs patching is, if less than 255 bytes].

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It didn't move anything. There is no ROM at the beginning of memory. As the system did not include any code in ROM at all by default, ROMs were optional and usually placed at the end of memory. ROM is not needed, because the front panel can be used to halt the CPU, enter a program into RAM without CPU intervention, and command the CPU to execute the code loaded from front panel.

So if there is a ROM installed, user must operate the front panel to make the CPU execute commands at the address where ROM is installed.

In a system with no ROM at all, user must operate the front panel to load in the code to RAM and to execute it.

Comment: It might be worth more explicitly mentioning that while some other "trainer" computers use a monitor program in ROM to operate a front-panel interface, the Altair front panel switches can be used to place data in RAM *without any CPU involvement whatsoever*.

Comment: @supercat This is not correct for the Altair. Unlike some other designs, the 8800 front panel _ran the CPU_ to execute its functions. See e.g. the [Theory of Operation Manual](http://dunfield.classiccmp.org/altair/d/88theory.pdf) p.6 where it explains how pressing the examine switch starts CPU execution as the panel puts a JMP followed by the switch-set address on the bus and then halts the processor. (The data bus values for the post-JMP instruction fetch are displayed on the data LEDs.)

Comment: If you think about it, any front panel that can set the program counter (or any other CPU register) on most microprocessors would _have_ to run the CPU itself to do this since there's no external access to registers. Front panels that directly set memory instead of using the CPU (such as the Altair 680) had to restart CPU execution at the location of the previous stop or at the reset address.

Comment: @cjs: Hmm... did the Altair use any kind of ROM chip, or did it just use hardwired arrangement of gates to form all of the necessary instructions?

Comment: @supercat That's described on the exact page I gave you. "When the Examine switch is depressed the counter (IC J) is started. On the first count, a jump instruction (JMP 303) is strobed directly onto the bi-directional data bus at the processor. This is accomplished by enabling 2 gates of IC 2 and 2 gates of IC D through the output pin 6 of one gate of IC T. These open collector gates then pull down data lines D2, D3, D4 and D5. This puts 303 on the data bus, which is the code for a JMP." The [schematic](http://dunfield.classiccmp.org/altair/d/88schema.pdf) is also in that directory.